# Installing TestInsight into Delphi 10 Seattle

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I am using Delphi 10 Seattle Pro and am unable to successfully install TestInsight into the IDE.  I have previously installed it into XE5 Pro without a hitch.

I downloaded the most recent builds, which are version 1.0 and version 1.1 which is designated specifically for XE8.  Neither works for D10.  First, I had to create a package using the units to install it, as the installer did not find D10.  When I tried to compile the package, I received the following error:

> [dcc32 Error] TestInsight.DUnitX.pas(20): E2291 Missing implementation
>   of interface method ITestLogger.OnTestingStarts

I have made sure to include the location of the TestInsight installation folder in my library search path, but for some reason, there is no TestInsight.dll in the directory.  The installation program apparently did not create one.

Is there a fix for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

TestInsight is not released for Seattle yet - and that API breaking change was one of the reasons.

We figured that out now so there is no difference anymore between the DUnitX version available on GitHub and the one shipped with Seattle so I will release it soon(tm).

Comment: TestInsight is now available for Seattle - Stefan, would you like to update your answer? (For others, use the download link found here: https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/testinsight/wiki/Home It was released on Oct 19: https://plus.google.com/+StefanGlienke/posts/K6b3gJRLaZB)